# Will Python unittest framework execute an overloaded setUp(self, another param) before each test method?

Tags: python, python-unittest

If I **overload** (not override)  the setUp method, will it still be executed before each test method?

If not, does it affect the execution of setUp() (the non-overloaded version)?

Answer (score 1):

Python does not support method overloading. The actual method will be the method which was defined last.

```
class A:
    def foo(self, arg_one): pass

    def foo(self, arg_one, arg_two): pass

A().foo('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: foo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg_two'
```

That is mostly because Python is dynamically typed language. Overloading rules would have been way too complicated if overloading was to be (somehow) supported.

Comment: While overloading is rarely used and likely to be unidiomatic, Python has had support for overloading via `@functools.singledispatch` in the stdlib since 3.4, released in 2014. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch

Comment: @goodside "likely to be unidiomatic" what an understatement... I'd cringe if I saw that in production code.

Comment: Perhaps, but "Python does not support method overloading" is also an overstatement. It's part of the stdlib and useful in rare cases. One would be writing a wrapper for an existing non-Python API that uses heavy overloading, where you want to maintain as much consistency as possible.